# Chrome DevTools Performance Layout missing code refere

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, pagespeed

I'm trying to find a solution for high Max Potential First Input Delay on a website I'm auditing. I'm evaluating all the Long Tasks once FMP is triggered. While most are being marked as Recalculated Style, I'm not getting the exact code location of where that is, as shown in the attached screenshot. 
Anyone has a recommendation of how to better evaluated the exact code causing the bottleneck
[Chrome DevTools Performance Long Task Missing script line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eQfM.png)

Reply to wOxxOm:
OK so to understand you are referring to the [Reveal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvQ8P.png) feature as opposed to the to [Bottom-up view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTbSw.png).

Comment: Switch to the `Summary` tab at the bottom and click `Recalculate style` in the chart.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Added screenshots to original question. It's the "reveal" link you where referring to I assume?